# Parsing a tab-separated file with missing fields 

Tags: python, parsing, csv

This is an example of a complex tab separated file I'm trying to parse

```
ENTRY   map0010\tNAME Glycolysis\tDESCRIPTION Glycolysis is the process of converting glucose into pyruvate\tCLASS   Metabolism\tDISEASE   H00071  Hereditary fructose intolerance\tH00072  Pyruvate dehydrogenase complex deficiency\tDBLINKS     GO: 0006096 0006094
ENTRY   map00020\tNAME  Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)\tCLASS   Metabolism; Carbohydrate Metabolism\tDISEASE   H00073  Pyruvate carboxylase deficiency\tDBLINKS     GO: 0006099\tREL_PATHWAY map00010  Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis\tmap00053  Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism
```

I'm trying to obtain an output containing only some fields, like:

```
ENTRY   map0010\tNAME Glycolysis\tCLASS   Metabolism\tDISEASE   H00071  Hereditary fructose intolerance H00072  Pyruvate dehydrogenase complex deficiency\tDBLINKS     GO: 0006096 0006094\tNA
ENTRY   map00020\tNAME  Citrate cycle (TCA cycle)\tCLASS   Metabolism; Carbohydrate Metabolism\tDISEASE   H00073  Pyruvate carboxylase deficiency\tDBLINKS     GO: 0006099\tREL_PATHWAY map00010  Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis\tmap00053  Ascorbate and aldarate metabolism
```

The main problem is that not all the rows contain the same number of fields, so I need to delete, for example, the fields containing the string "DESCRIPTION", and add an empty field in the rows where the field "CLASS" in not present.

Moreover for some fields the data are split in more than one (f.i, line 1 the field following DISEASE contains disease data!) and I need to join them.

I've tried with:

```
input = open('file', 'r')

dict = ["ENTRY", "NAME", "CLASS", "DISEASE", "DBLINKS", "REL_PATHWAY"]

split_tab = []
output = []

for line in input:
    split_tab.append(line.split('\t'))

for item in dict:
    for element in split_tab:
        if item in element:
            output.append(element)
        else:
            output.append('\tNA\t')
```

But it keeps everything, not only the elements specified in dict. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: So, what is the actual format / grammer?

Comment: @Stuart, it's a tab-separated file (maybe I didn't understand your question).

Comment: It appears that each row explicitly names the fields, separated by white space and then the value, separated by tab:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the built in [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) library. Your job will be much easier.

For some sample code:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('myfile.csv', 'rb'), dialect='excel-tab')
fieldnames = ['Name','Class']
writer = csv.DictWriter(open('myfile.csv', 'rb'), fieldnames, restval='', extrasaction='ignore', dialect='excel-tab')

for row in reader:
    newrow = {}
    for field in row:
        key = field.split(' ', 1)[0]
        newrow[key] = field
    writer.writerow(newrow)
```

Pay particular attention to how the DictWriter is set up. It is *much* easier to use if you include the `restval` and `extrasaction` fields. They allow you to pass a dictionary with more or less values than the writer is expecting.

Simply have your fieldnames set appropriately, and set up the reader to use the correct dialect. This may include adding your own, but the csv link has instructions on how to do that.

**EDIT**

After Rob's comment posted below, I've revised this to take into account the fact that csv dialects are not as powerful as I thought.

Comment: This won't work.  The DictReader class wants the field names to be given or to be the first line of data.  Sonny's data has the field names embedded in the fields on every line, and arbitrary fields can be missing (not just empty).  For example, column 3 might be "DESCRIPTION", or it might be "CLASS"; you have to look at the field contents on each line to know what field it is.  If a Dialect can handle this, the documentation certainly doesn't explain how.

Comment: @robmayoff I'm arbitrarily setting the fieldnames, with the included variable. The rest would be setting up a new dialect as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params). Note that he will probably need to subclass the dialect variable if it has mixed fields with the fieldname embedded in it.

Comment: "I'm arbitrarily setting the fieldnames" - on the DictWriter.  You're not setting any fieldnames on the DictReader.  "... as explained [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params)."  That documentation doesn't explain how to use a Dialect to determine fieldnames.  In fact, a Dialect *cannot* determine fieldnames.  Check the source ([csv.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/555871844962/Lib/csv.py) [_csv.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/555871844962/Modules/_csv.c)).

Comment: @robmayoff My apologies, I misread your comment. I was referring to the DictWriter, which isn't relevant. I checked the source, so I could provide an example, and found out it isn't quite as useful as I had expected. I've edited my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 3):

```
requiredKeys = 'ENTRY NAME CLASS DISEASE DBLINKS REL_PATHWAY'.split(' ')

for line in open('file', 'r'):
    fields = line.split('\t')
    fieldMap = {}
    for field in fields:
        key = field.split(' ', 1)[0]
        fieldMap[key] = field
    print '\t'.join([fieldMap.get(key, 'NA') for key in requiredKeys])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line

> split_tab.append(line.split('\t'))

is messing this up. Your making a list inside a list. try this instead:

> split_tab = line.split('\t')

Comment: Could someone please explain why my answer gets so little appreciation? I spotted the problem with the code - the two other answers, although great, gave different ways of doing it. no love for pointing out a simple mistake? It's a cold world

Comment: Your answer is correct, which is why nobody is downvoting it. But, he's replicating functionality that already exists in python, so he ends up with a less functional and more error prone code base.

Comment: Thanks man, that made a lot of sense! (Edit: that may be construed as sarcastic, but that was not my intention!)